# Problem with persistent states within embedded function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am currently implementing a second order low-pass filter employing Tustin discretization as embedded function within a Simulink model. The function has currently deployed as follows:

```
function y = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u,fn,dn,Ts)

persistent xs
if isempty(xs)
    xs = [u 0]';
end

% Convert frequency from Hz to rad/s
wn = fn*2*pi;

% Construct state-space matrices in continuous time
A = [0 1 ; -wn^2 -2*dn*wn];
B = [0 ; wn^2];
C = [1 0];
D = 0;

% Construct equivalent state-space matrices in discrete time
I = eye(size(A));
K1 = (I + 0.5*A*Ts);
K2 = (I - 0.5*A*Ts)^-1;
Ad = K1*K2;
Bd = K2*B*Ts;
Cd = C*K2;
Dd = (0.5*Ts*C*K2*B) + D;

% Calculate output
xs = Ad*xs + Bd*u;
y  = Cd*xs + Dd*u;

end
```

I am then calling such function from within another function which looks like this:

```
function u1 = fcn(u,fn,dn,Ts)

u1 = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u(1),fn,dn,Ts);
```

In all those cases when I call the function a single time, as in the case

```
y1 = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u1,fn,dn,Ts);
```

the results are ok
[image: Figure 1. Filtering single signal]

However, as soon as I would like to filter multiple signals concurrently, as in the following case

```
function [u1,u2,u3] = fcn(u,fn,dn,Ts)

u1 = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u(1),fn,dn,Ts);
u2 = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u(2),fn,dn,Ts);
u3 = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u(3),fn,dn,Ts);
```

the results are poor as in Figure 2.
[image: Figure 2. Multiple signal filtering]

I believe that it has to do with the persistent state variable `xs`, which should undergo a reset or initialization as soon as the `SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u,fn,dn,Ts)` is being called.

I have tried different things out, unfortunately with little success. Therefore, your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't show a case where the variable needs to persist between function calls. Did you think about simply not making it a persistent variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the persistent variable is not reset when calling the filter function the second and third time, and thus the initial `xs` is not set correctly. Since you want to use the function for multiple signals, the persistent variable cannot be inside `SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin`.

You can however let this function output `xs` and take `xs` as input argument, and keep this persistent in `fcn`.

```
function [y, xs] = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u,fn,dn,Ts,xs)

    if isempty(xs)
        xs = [u 0].';
    end

    % Convert frequency from Hz to rad/s
    wn = fn*2*pi;

    % continue with the rest...

end
```

And `fcn` would look like:

```
function [u1,u2,u3] = fcn(u,fn,dn,Ts)

    persistent x1 x2 x3

    % x1, x2 and x3 will be [] on first iteration, thus xs will be set to [u 0].'
    [u1,x1] = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u(1),fn,dn,Ts,x1);
    [u2,x2] = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u(2),fn,dn,Ts,x2);
    [u3,x3] = SecondOrderLowpassFilterTustin(u(3),fn,dn,Ts,x3);

end
```

BTW, don't think you expect any complex output, but just in case `'` is not transpose, `.'` is.